Can't connect android phone to Kubuntu 22.04
After I plug it in with a usb-c cable and enable USB file transfer, I get the following error in dolphin:

No storage media found. Make sure your device is unlocked and has MTP
enabled in its USB connection settings.

I already have the packages installed: mtp-tools, gvfs-backends
Here is the output from mtp-detect:
$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.19

Listing raw device(s)
avoid probing device using attached kernel interface
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 7, dev 7
Attempting to connect device(s)
libusb_claim_interface() reports device is busy, likely in use by GVFS or KDE MTP device handling alreadyLIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.

I was able to use the workaround of connecting my phone before opening Dolphin, however I would like this to work every time, even if Dolphin is already open.

The error is clearly from the phone.

The error is clearly from the Ubuntu system. It looks like the phone was auto mounted. Find it with cat /etc/mtab. Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.
